# Sqlite: Setting default value for a max sub-query if result is null

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, default, max

I want to increment a sequence number for subgroups within a table, but if the subgroup does not exist then the sequence should start with 1:

For example, in the following, we want sequence to be set to 1 if there exists no records in the table with `class=5`; if there exists such records, then sequence should take the value max sequence (in the subgroup `class=5`) + 1:

```
update order set class=5, sequence=(select max(sequence) from order 
where class=5)+1 where order_id=104;
```

The problem is the above doesn't work for the initial case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In these situations, function [`COALESCE()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) comes very handy:

```
UPDATE order
SET class = 5,
    sequence = coalesce(
        (SELECT max(sequence)
         FROM order 
         WHERE class=5),
        0
    ) + 1
WHERE order_id = 104
```

Another good thing about `COALESCE` that it is supported by most other SQL engines - MySQL, Postgres, etc...

Comment: hm, thats worth a upvote, because of the "works with most" addition... my awfull self always googles "NVL SQL-Engine Name alternative" ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Just surround your query with the `IFNULL( QUERY, 0 )` function

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull